# <JS> This Inside Function of A Function And This Inside Method of An Object

Tags: javascript

```js
function A() {
  return function B() {
    return this;
  };
}
```

```
A = {
  B: function B() {
    return this;
  }
};
```

Why `this`in the `B()` return window object instead of the `function A()` object? Function in JS is an object, so why is it behaving different which is shown in the second code sample?

Comment: because 'this' is a keyword which holds the scope of the function and not the function

Comment: @JayabalajiJ Function in JS is an object, so the 'this' keyword in B() should be returning the A() function object instead of window.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `B` is just declared in the function `A`, it has nothing else with function `A`, except the scope. Every function has it own context to which `this` refers. By default (means no explicit/implicit bindings, no object) `this` refers to the `window` object in `non strict` mode and to the `undefined` in `strict` mode.

**Non strict mode**

```js
function A() {
  return this;
}

console.log(A());
```

**Strict mode**

```js
'use strict';

function A() {
   return this;
}

console.log(A());
```

**Explicit binding**

```js
'use strict';

const obj = { name: 'Object' };

function A() {
   return this;
}

console.log(A.call(obj));
```

**Object binding**

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'Object',
  A() {
     return this;
  }
}

console.log(obj.A());
```

Comment: This is not the answer I am looking for. I am asking why B() this keyword inside A() return window.

Comment: Have you read the above part ? Your function B is just declared in the function A, it has nothing else with function A, except the scope. Every function has it own context to which this refers. By default (means no explicit/implicit bindings, no object) this refers to the window object in non strict mode and to the undefined in strict mode.

Comment: Function in JS is an object, so 'this' keyword in B() should be returning empty A() object instead of window.